# Android: invalidate(dirty)

Tags: android, android-canvas, invalidation

It seems like Android really doesn't like `invalidate (Rect dirty)`, which is used to invalidate only part of a canvas.  When I invalidate part of a canvas (shown in green below) and a `ToggleButton` *outside* of the canvas needs to be redrawn at the same time, the entire region shown in red is erased!  It seems as though Android is just invalidating everything within the smallest rectangle encompassing the union of the two regions that need to be redrawn, even if one of the regions is outside of the View whose canvas I'm invalidating.

Is this standard behaviour, and if so, why would anyone use partial invalidation?

[image]

Comment: how to stop android from erasing the red area and only redraw the green area, i have use invalidate(rect) in my own implementation but don't know how to handle that inside onDraw() when call goes from invalidate() to onDraw()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Android has a class called `ViewRootImpl`. This class is owned by every window you see on the screen (the term window is a little confusing here, so for this explanation a window is the main activity's layout without any dialogs or popups on top).
This layout is being traversed all the time, meaning that Android is just waiting to have a dirty rectangle for this window and draw it. Since this window may contain many views (buttons etc.) it goes through all of them and asks each one whether it needs redrawing.
Each view returns a dirty rectangle to `ViewRootImpl` and all these rectangles are joined to one big rectangle that is redrawn in the end.

Why does it do that? well, the `ViewRootImpl` asks the `WindowManagerService` for one `Canvas` to draw on. This means that all views in one window actually share a `Canvas` everytime there is a traversal.

As to your question, if only one specific `View` had a dirty rectangle then only that dirty rectangle would be drawn, but since another view had one as well then the dirty rectangle contains both.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is caused by hardware acceleration. You must disable it in your activity in order to use `invalidate(dirty rect)`. To disable the hardware acceleration in your activity open the manifest file and add:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Now you can use the `invalidate(dirty rect)`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! This is not mentioned in the documentation of this function despite I think it is pretty important to know. I spent half a day in investigate why the whole view was invalidated.

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 28. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#invalidate(android.graphics.Rect)